# what is ^@ character in vi?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix, vim, vi

I am seeing a lot of `^@` character in a contents of a text file on my UNIX server. I am unable to understand what does `^@` mean? and how to remove them from the file? and above all why it is generated?

If i try to see the contents of the file using `cat` , I am getting this:

```
u3210#"! utypyado
```

however if try to use `cat -v` , i am getting `^@` characters (as attached screenshot) along with some text in english. Same output is observed when i use `vi` with `:set list` command.

Any help is much appreciated , thanks very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Its a null byte. (You can type it by doing `<C-v>000`)

Comment: could he be looking at a binary file?

Comment: Its a `.htaccess` file for apache , so it should not be containing a NULL character. thanks for your efforts and time, or is there any possibility that my file is corrupt?

Comment: I found something here.I am wondering if i am attacked? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45955/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-file-name-with-null-bytes-in-serialized-instances

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the comments say `^@` is actually a null byte (`\x00`) in your file.

If you want to get rid of all null byte instances then you can use this  command in `vi`:

```
:%s/[\x0]//g
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava , i got it now, but i don't understand on what circumstances they are created or generated?

Comment: I have seen them present in log files usually. Presence of null bytes in `.htaccess` is rare since these files are edited manually most of the times. Most likely due to some rewrite rules generator you may have used in the past, just a guess.

Comment: @anubhava For me this deletes all occurrences of `0`.

Comment: Try with `[` and `]`

Answer (score 1):

You can answer the question yourself:  at least, the "what character is this" part, not the "how did it get here" part.  From `:help ga`:

```
Print the ascii value of the character under the
cursor in decimal, hexadecimal and octal.  For
example, when the cursor is on a 'R':
        <R>  82,  Hex 52,  Octal 122
```

For more details and related commands, see the full entry.